# What performance metrics(Reads/Writes/CPU/Duration) of a stored procedure change and what remains almost same on a busy vs idle sql server

Tags: performance, cpu, procedure, duration

What performance metrics(Reads/Writes/CPU/Duration) of a stored procedure change  and what remains almost same on a busy vs idle sql server ? My understanding is Reads & Writes always remains same (almost) irrespective of the load of the SQL Server. Duration can be high due to locks and other resource contention. I am not sure about CPU. Can someone explain how & why the metrics change or does not change between a idle vs a busy server.